# Комп виснет в убунте

Tags: ubuntu

Здравствуйте.
Такой вопрос:
Имеется древний ноут, который зависает постоянно, но при движении мышкой тут же отвисает. На нем стоит убунту - пишу в консоли команды, они не появляются на экране до движения мышкой. Систему переустанавливал - то же самое. Думаю, что проблема в железе. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком именно?

Comment: А что происходит, если печатать вне иксов, когда мышь не работает?

Нажмите `Ctrl + Alt + F1`, попробуйте поработать в консоли. Что происходит?

Comment: А отладчика то нету :P

Comment: Помогающих долго не было, отладчик отчаявшись ушел курить.

Comment: Без иксов то же самое. Первый час еще более-менее, потом начинает подвисать, а через некоторое время комп просто повисает. acpi -t = начинается с 50.8, со временем доползает до 65. hddtemp  - начинается с 30, поднимается где-то до 45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так, давайте локализуем проблемму:

Прогоните `memtest`. Если все нормально, то:

```
$ cat /dev/urandom | gzip --best > /dev/null
```

Это должно быстро прогреть процессор, но не трогать HDD.

Если прогреется, но не повалится, то займемся жестким диском:

```
$ while true; do dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/hothdd bs=1M count=100; done
```

Comment: прогрев процессора как ни странно пошел на пользу. где-то на 68С тормоза прекратились.
прогрев жесткого диска на производительности никак не сказался.
неужели нужно прогревать проц?

Comment: а есть ли команда, которая не быстро бы прогревала процессор или вовсе его не прогревала, но чем-нибудь занимала? судя по всему, его надо чем-то занимать.

Comment: Можно, конечно, запустить что-то типа такого:

    $ nice -n 19 gzip --fast < /dev/urandom > /dev/null

Но покажите, пожалуйста, сначала вот это:

    $ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
    $ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors

Comment: "Нет такого файла или каталога". и на tab после cpu никак не реагиует. ls /sys/devices/system/cpu power subsysten type uevent

Comment: Если честно, у меня кончились догадки.

А другие дистрибутивы точно так же работают, или только Ubuntu?